# How to schedule a c# application?

Tags: c#

I have developed one birthday reminder application. i wanted to **schedule** this application to run in every 1 hour.

Comment: The UI schuduler only lets you run daily.  I did this before Windows 7 so you may have more tools now.  What I had to do was schedule a task to run in the start up and then I would have the task also reschedule itself for current time plus one hour.

Comment: @BalamBalam That's simply not true, and wasn't true in Windows XP either.

Comment: OK then I am missing something.  When I open the Scheduler the options I see are Monthy, Weekly, Daily, One Time, and Trigger.  I can set the time of day.  Where is the option for hourly?

Comment: "Repeat task every ___ hours"

Comment: OK I found the hours - thanks.  +1

Answer (score 10):

Use the [Windows task scheduler.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would make it a console application or service application and use the windows task scheduler to schedule it to run hourly. Make sure you have error handling to alert you in case if fails for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but you can use [Quartz .Net library](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).